# How to fix this error in char and NSString

Tags: ios, unix, terminal, deb, theos

I'm trying to put the NSString that holds an modified path cuz i can't use path"/subfolder"
My code is:

```
NSString *bath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/path", path];
pid_t pid;
int status;
const char *argv[] = {"mkdir", bath, NULL};
posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/mkdir", NULL, NULL, (char* const*)argv, NULL);
waitpid(pid, &status, WEXITED);`
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ws5N.jpg

Answer (score 0):

NSStrings need to be converted into C strings before you can include them in your `argv` array.

do this:

```
NSString *bath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/path", path];
const char *cBath = [bath UTF8String];
if (cBath == NULL)
{
    print("cBath is null ; why is path also null?");
    return;
}
pid_t pid;
int status;
const char *argv[] = {"mkdir", cBath, NULL};
posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/mkdir", NULL, NULL, (char* const*)argv, NULL);
waitpid(pid, &status, WEXITED);`
```

Comment: I added a bit of error checking.  You should make sure bath is a valid.